# how to create an academic months in excel pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am trying to create a row of months that is sorted in an academic year.  When I put the data into a Pivot table it keeps defaulting from Jan- Dec.  When I want it to be September to August.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using a drop down list and Vlookup function? Choose your month in the drop down list and then the details you want to extract with Vlookup/Hlookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom sort order. When sorting, in the dialog box for months, drop down the "Sort A-Z" option and choose Custom List. You can then type in your desired sort order

Comment: Sorry this is not working for me.  I have tried this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3rOXxzfRyIg but don't understand how it get sorted using the custom list.